# Can't setup mail server on Azure Virtual Machine with ARM

Tags: email-server, virtual-machines, azure

I just moved my class VM server to the new VM in Azure but I am having trouble doing a reverse DNS on the VM. Speaking with Azure they sent me this link below.  Are they telling me I can't even host my own mail server???????

> "Sending outbound e-mail to external domains (such as outlook.com,
>   gmail.com, etc) directly from an e-mail server hosted in Azure compute
>   services is not supported due to the elastic nature of public cloud
>   service IPs and the potential for abuse.  As such, the Azure compute
>   IP address blocks are added to public block lists (such as the
>   Spamhaus PBL).  There are no exceptions to this policy."

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2016/04/04/sending-e-mail-from-azure-compute-resource-to-external-domains/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is not recommended approach. Reverse DNS can be set up, for example, you can go with that - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt126026.aspx and set up, but i would recommend to set up the external one or use SendGrid from Azure Marketplace. I believe that was done for the security sake.

Comment: I had reverse DNS setup on the classic VM and worked just fine, no issues being blocked.  Now the new VM wont let me set it at all.

Comment: What did you do? Did you try the powershell?

Comment: I went back to the classic server which was working PERFECT and will stick with that.